# Add an exception after a loop with If

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to accept only Alpha and one special character which is: "-". There is my code with specar="-", but this variable/function doesn't work in the loop. Any idea of why?

```
def demander_le_nom():
    reponse_nom = (input("Quel est votre nom?"))
    specar = "-"
    for chart in reponse_nom:
        if not reponse_nom.isalpha():
            print("Erreur!")
            reponse_nom = (input("Quel est votre nom?"))
        else:
            pass
    return reponse_nom
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: specar isn't a condition if your if statement, so why would it apply?

Comment: You did not specify anywhere in your loop about the special character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the condition for the special character

```
def demander_le_nom():
    reponse_nom = (input("Quel est votre nom?"))
    specar = "-"
    for chart in reponse_nom:
        if not reponse_nom.isalpha() or chart == specar:
            print("Erreur!")
            reponse_nom = (input("Quel est votre nom?"))
        else:
            pass
    return reponse_nom
```

Comment: I think you need `if not reponse_nom.isalpha() and chart != specar`

Comment: It's up to him if he needs to force the user to put the special character. In this case, you are right and he needs and instead of or.